# Is there no way to control the concat order of Gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've tried gulp-order, I've tried renaming files, and most recently I've tried just explicitly listing the scripts in the src like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src([
    './js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './js/moment-with-locales.min.js',
    './js/jquery.fancybox.min.js'
])
.pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
})
```

No matter what I do the output of bundle.js is not following the order that I need. For what it's worth the order does not change randomly when using concat it is the same order every time. But it's not alphabetical...

During my research it appears that the issue may be that my gulpfile.js changes are not being applied and I may need to "restart" gulp. That being said, I cannot find any information on how to "restart" gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't gulp-concat that was changing the order. The order was being changed by gulp-uglify.

I was able to solve this problem by doing the uglify before the concat. Like so:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src([
    './js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './js/moment-with-locales.min.js',
    './js/jquery.fancybox.min.js'
])
  .pipe(uglify())
.pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
})
```